# Discord.py adding a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am trying to make a command, my code:

```
global_reps = {}
@client.command()
async def global(ctx, top):

        
    co2 = dict(sorted(global_reps.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10])
    print(co2)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f'Global',
        description = f'Reputation leaderboard',
        color = random.choice(cols),
        timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
    )
    ccc = [1]
    to = list(co2.values())
    top = sum(to)
    top = int(top)
        
    for k, v in co2.items():
        percs = '{:.0%}'.format(v/top)

        k = int(k)
        m = client.get_user(k)
        if len(ccc) == 1:
            e = ''

        elif len(ccc) == 2:
            e = ''

        elif len(ccc) == 3:
            e = ''

        else:
            e = ''
        embed.add_field(name=f'{len(ccc)}.{e}{m.name}#{m.discriminator}', value=f"> Rep points: **{v}**\n> Top: **{percs}**")
        ccc.append(1)
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Active at: ')
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But in this line:

```
async def global(ctx, top):
```

Python 'thinks' that I try to use `global` keyword. But I just want it to become a command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually **is** a way to do this:

```
@client.command(name="global")
async def THIS_COULD_HAVE_ANY_NAME_NOW(ctx, top):
    # now define your command here
```